# How can I change the PATH for all users and all shells?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path, zsh

I'm on a Linux Mint system and I use bash and zsh as shells. I've just manually installed Texlive and I want it to be in my path.

I thought adding the following lines to `.profile` would be fine, but zsh does not load .profile.

```
if [ -d "/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux" ] ; then
    PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux:$PATH"
fi

if [ -d "/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux" ] ; then
    PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
fi

if [ -d "/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/man" ] ; then
    MANPATH="/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH"
fi

if [ -d "/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/info" ] ; then
    INFOPATH="/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH"
fi
```

Obviously, everything that mentions "add it to .zshrc / .bashrc" cannot be correct, as this will only affect me (only one user) and only those two shells.

(I have administrative rights on my machine.)

Comment: For `zsh`, see the section "STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES" in `man zsh`. `zsh` has a lengthy, but well-defined, sequence of files that it reads on startup.

Answer (score 2):

ZSH reads /etc/zsh/zprofile. So change that file.

Comment: It's `/etc/zprofile`, but it's possible for a user to prevent this file from being read by setting `NO_GLOBAL_RCS` in his/her `.zshenv` file.

Comment: @chepner On debian (I am on Debian 7 now) based systems it is /etc/zsh/zprofile . There is no /etc/zprofile file.

Comment: Ah, there must be a compile time option to specify which directory. Do you have `/etc/zsh/zshenv` instead of `/etc/zshenv` as well?

Comment: @chepner Yes i have /etc/zsh/zshenv . It is the default location for the package which was installed with apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `/etc/profile` & `/etc/bash_bashrc`, those apply for all users.

Comment: Ok, but I'm pretty sure that this will not apply to zsh.

Comment: edit: I've just tried it with `echo $PATH`. This does not work for `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

`bash`, `ksh`, `dash`, `sh`, and other shells related to `sh` all start by reading `/etc/profile`.

---

For `zsh`, I would recommend putting the change in `/etc/zshenv`. On the plus side, this file is *guaranteed* to be sourced, and sourced first, by any interactive `zsh`. On the minus side, it's guaranteed :), so don't put anything time-consuming here. Adding a few directories to `PATH` shouldn't be time-consuming, though.

Any of the other `zsh` startup files may or may not be read, depending on the settings in the user's private `.zshenv` file, which is the second file to be sourced.

---

For `csh` and its derivatives, `/etc/csh.cshrc` is probably the best bet.

For any shells I may have missed, you'll have to consult their documentation.

---

For *any* shell, be sure to check the documentation on your system to verify the location of the shells' files; they may be different depending on how the shell was compiled.

Comment: I've put the lines from above (exactly like I wrote them there!) in `/etc/zsh/zshenv` and in `/etc/zsh/zprofile` and in `/etc/profile`. When I source any of those files the path is ok. But as soon as I close MATE terminal 1.6.1 the path is like it was before. Do you have any idea how to fix this? (Same for bash)

Comment: Sourcing a file only changes the environment of that shell (or any of its children). Make sure that the files you are editing are the files that are automatically sourced by a new shell.